# Java do while loop has problems in LinkedList

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, do-while, singly-linked-list

I have this LinkedList where I am facing an issue in printList() module.

```
public class LinkedList {
    LinkedList next;
    int data;
    public LinkedList(int data) {
        this.data = data;
        this.next = null;
    }
    public void append(int... data) {
        int size = data.length;
        for(int i=0; i<size; i++)   {
            append(data[i]);
        }
    }
    public void append(int data)    {
        LinkedList head = this;
        while(head.next!=null)  {
            head = head.next;
        }
        head.next = new LinkedList(data);
    }
    public void printList() {
        LinkedList head = this;
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        do  {
            sb.append(head.data+", ");
            head=head.next;
        }   while(head.next!=null);
        System.out.println(sb.toString());
        while(head.next!=null)  {
            sb.append(head.data+", ");
            head=head.next;
        }   
        System.out.println(sb.toString());
    }
}
```

But the do while in printList prints the same as normal while. Why is that? Can some one help me?

Thanks 
Jeevan

Comment: What output do you get and what output are you expecting?

Comment: You created your own StringBuilder to avoid creating additional ones which are needed to perform concatenation, So why are you using `sb.append(head.data+", ");` instead of `sb.append(head.data).append(", ");`?

Comment: The second while loop in `printList` will do nothing since the first while loop end when `head.next` is null and you don't reset `head` before starting the second loop.

Comment: @Eran: It isn't printing the last element in both case

Comment: @Pshemo: ya that is a nice idea

Comment: Also why are you using `StringBuffer` instead of `StringBuilder` or `StringJoiner` (added in Java 8)?

Comment: @Eran: I tried putting them in different methods, why isn't both printing the last element?

Comment: @jeevan because you finish the loops when `head.next` is null. You should finish the loops when `head` is null.

Answer (score 1):

Since after the first while loop `head.next` is null, the second while loop is never entered.

Therefore this code:

```
public void printList() {
    LinkedList head = this;
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    do  {
        sb.append(head.data+", ");
        head=head.next;
    }   while(head.next!=null);
    System.out.println(sb.toString());
    while(head.next!=null)  {
        sb.append(head.data+", ");
        head=head.next;
    }   
    System.out.println(sb.toString());
}
```

is equivalent to this code:

```
public void printList() {
    LinkedList head = this;
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    do  {
        sb.append(head.data+", ");
        head=head.next;
    }   while(head.next!=null);
    System.out.println(sb.toString());  
    System.out.println(sb.toString());
}
```

i.e. you are printing the same `StringBuffer` instance having the same contents twice.

EDIT:

If you want the last element to be printed, change

```
while(head.next!=null)
```

to

```
while(head!=null)
```

Comment: I tried putting them in different methods, why isn't both printing the last element. Do while one should print one more than normal while, why isn't it doing that?

Answer (score 1):

Problem with your printing method is that in case of last elemment

```
        head=head.next;
    }   while(head.next!=null);
```

`head` will store its reference, but since it is last element it doesn't have next element after it, which means that condition `head.next!=null` will stop your loop before you will be able to append `data` in this element.

You can rewrite your method to something like

```
public void printList() {
    LinkedList head = this;
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    sb.append(head.data); // read data from current element
    while(head.next!=null){               // if there is next element
        head = head.next;                 // visit it
        sb.append(", ").append(head.data);// and read its data
    };
    System.out.println(sb.toString());
}
```

which for me is little more readable.

Answer (score 0):

I think all of the above solutions are good, but I just wanted to give you list like print method :-)

```
public void printList() {
    Node temp = this.next;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append(data).append("-->");
    while (temp != null) {
        sb.append(temp.data).append("-->");
        temp= temp.next;
    }
    sb.append("NULL");
    return sb.toString();
}
```